# How do I swap Y and Z axis on bone?

Tags: bones, axis

For some reason Blender 2.8 creates bones with Y axis going vertical (up-down) and Z axis going horizontal (front-back). I need to align bone axis to global axis, where Z is up-down and Y is front-back (as seen at picture). How can I do so?

[image]

I'm trying to follow [this guy's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMnH9vvMLYg), but for some reason when he creates bones they have correct axis placement bu default, and my blender swaps Y and Z axis.

Comment: you can't align the bone axis on the global axis unless you rotate it of course: R x -90, but I guess it's not what you mean, but what moment in the video are you referring to?

Comment: at 3:10 he selects bone and you can clearly see bone's axis are facing same directions as global ones

Comment: these are not the bone axis, these are the global and they are displayed for any selected object, the bone axis are still the same, if he had chosen to display it you would see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the bone local axis, for example the tail will always point to the local Y axis.

I think you are confusing the global axes and the local axes. Actually when you choose to display the bone axes (in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Display*) it will display the local axes of each selected bone. Same as if you switch the *Transformation Ortientation* dropdown menu from *Global* to *Local* and select a bone, as you can see in my screenshots.

It's useful to display all the bone axes as it allows to align the axes of several bones, for example.

You can change the bone (and not axis) orientation in *Edit* mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and align it with the global with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. When you'll create some bone poses in *Pose* mode, you'll use <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate and <kbd>X</kbd> for example to rotate on the global X axis, and double <kbd>X</kbd> to rotate on the local X axis.

[image]

Comment: This answer is correct as this is not currently possible in Blender. That being said I think there is a strong case to make this into a feature. I explain this in more detail on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/dzhbbc/).

Comment: ok I've upvoted your proposition  ;)